# dojoJS Solr connector - pass out (return) data

Tags: javascript, rest, solr, dojo

I am new to accessing json data from rest services like Solr and ElasticSearch with JS and the dojo framework.
In this case I have used `dojo` to write `solr.js` which contains a simple function that uses `JSONP` params with `dojo.io.script` to connect to a Solr index. Now I need to get the function to pass out (return) the data that gets from Solr. This is how I want to call the function:

```
<script src="solr.js"></script>
<script>
var mySolrData = solrStore(
"http://solrUrl/", 
"indexName/select"
);
</script>
```

This is the code for the `solr.js` file that contains the function I am calling:

```
dojo.require("dojo.io.script");
function solrStore (indexURL, collectionPath, wt, rows, start, q) {
  //set some default values//
  wt = typeof wt  !== 'undefined' ? wt : 'json';
  rows = typeof rows !== 'undefined' ? rows : '25';
  start = typeof start !== 'undefined' ? start : '1';
  q = typeof q !== 'undefined' ? q : '*';

  //arguments for jsonp to connect to solr index//
  var jsonpArgs = 
    {
        url: indexURL + collectionPath,
        labelAttribute:"solr",
        handleAs: "json",
        callbackParamName: "json.wrf",
        content: {
            wt: wt,
            rows: rows,
            start: start,
            q: q
        //end content vars//
        },
        //load the data
        load: function(data){
            //set the value of the raw response data
            var mySolrStore = data;
            //view the data in the console 
            console.log(mySolrStore.response.docs);
            return mySolrStore.response;
        //end load data//
        },
        //on error show in the console
        error: function(error){
            console.log("An error occured connecting to the Solr index: " + error);
          //end on error
          } 
         //end arguments for jsonp
         };
        //get the data with dojo.io.script.get
        dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs);
}
```

When I execute the code in the browser I see the data that need in the console log when it hits the load: part. However, I am having a brain-fart on how I can pull that data out of the function into the page where I call the function because no matter how I try it says it is `undefined`.

What am I missing that I need to do to get the data I retrieve from the solrStore function into the `mySolrData` var?

Comment: I guess the response that you are receiving is in text/plain format, and you are expecting a json response by mentioning handleAs:"json". Try converting the plain text into json, using JSON.parse(json);

Comment: @ShadAmez, When I call it I see the data as Objects in the log where I  call `console.log(mySolrStore.response.docs);` So I know it is working there. I just need to return that response properly so I can use it in the code that calls the function.

Answer (score 0):

The variable mySolrStore is defined inside the asynchronous function "load:".
If I am not wrong you cannot return(catch values) from an asynchronous function since the context is different.

```
//set the value of the raw response data
var mySolrStore = data;
```

I would suggest that you define the variable outside the "load:". For instance you could define it before and

```
var mySolrStore;
//arguments for jsonp to connect to solr index//
var jsonpArgs = .....
```

and set the data value inside the load: call.

```
   load: function(data){
        //set the value of the raw response data
        mySolrStore = data;
```

Hope it solves issue.